# How to search for records with special characters which are not present in either English or Spanish alphabet?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has records with special characters in a production environment for data correction. Now the DB can have data which contain either English or Spanish characters. So I need to find only those special characters which do not belong to either of these alphabets. For example, I can have data like the following:

[image]

Here the character `Ñ` is correct because it is a spanish character, but the second one is not. The query I have written is the following but it fetches all the above and not only the second one.

```
select customerid,customername
from prodschema.prodtable
where not regexp_like(customername, '.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 .{}\[\]].*') and 
customernamelike 'YOLANDA RIOS CAS%';
```

So what should be the correct query for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
with t as 
(
select 'YOLANDA RIOS CASTANO' str from dual
union all select 'YOLANDA RIOS CASTAÑO' str from dual
union all select 'YOLANDA RIOS CASTA°O' str from dual
)
select str,
       length(regexp_replace(str, '[a-z[=n=] ]', null, 1, 0, 'i'))
       as cnt_not_recognized_chars
  from t;

STR                  CNT_NOT_RECOGNIZED_CHARS
-------------------- ------------------------
YOLANDA RIOS CASTANO                         
YOLANDA RIOS CASTAÑO                         
YOLANDA RIOS CASTA°O                        1

3 rows selected.
```

Find additional details here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/ap_posix001.htm

Answer (score 0):

Return the ASCII value for your column customername, and remove like that. Just for future you could set the column to have a Accent Sensitivity collation.

```
SELECT  ASCII(CustomerName)
FROM prodschema.prodtable
WHERE ASCII(CustomerName) != Value
```